# I create view for homepage but first index different from other index

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout

I'm new flutter dev

So I have homepage with a list of item, but my first index of item show different from another.

[image: Screenshot]

This is my code for home page :
home.dart

```
       Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: recProvider.getRecList(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  List<ModelKost>? data = snapshot.data as List<ModelKost>?;
                  int index = 0;
                  return Column(
                    children: data!.map((item) {
                      index++;
                      return Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: index == 1 ? 0 : 18,
                        ),
                        child: ItemView(item),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  );
                }
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
```

and this it widget list item
item_view.dart

```
class ItemView extends StatelessWidget {
  final ModelKost kostmodel;

  ItemView(this.kostmodel);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    DetailPage(kostmodel, kostmodel.id.toString())));
      },
      child: Row(
        children: [
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 130,
              width: 110,
              child: Image.network(
                kostmodel.fotoKost,
                width: 130,
                height: 110,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) {
                  if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                },
                errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) =>
                    const Text('gagal memuat gambar'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 25,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 120,
            width: 130,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  kostmodel.namaKost,
                  // "${widget.list[widget.index]["nama_kost"]}",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 4),
                Text(
                  kostmodel.alamatKost,
                  // "${widget.list[widget.index]['deskripsi']}",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      color: Colors.grey[500],
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 8),
                Text("Fasilitas",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 12,
                        color: Colors.grey[500],
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                Text(
                  kostmodel.fasilitas,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12,
                      color: Colors.grey[500],
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 8,
                ),
                Text.rich(
                  TextSpan(
                    text: 'Rp.${kostmodel.harga}',
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                    ),
                    children: const [
                      TextSpan(
                        text: ' / bulan',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What's wrong with my code above?
widget itemView looks weird, if I add bordercircular on itemview widget the first index not change at all.

Comment: Failed to reproduce the issue, My guess is it is getting from `margin`.

Comment: it's happing because your image is small for first widget, if you change `fit: BoxFit.cover,` to `fit: BoxFit.fill`, it will look same, though your image will stretch.

Comment: I found the problem here, 
i remove 
`SizedBox(
 height: 130,
  width: 110,`
thanks for answer @YeasinSheikh, @Ruchit

Answer (score 0):

call index++ before the column widget;

```
return Column(
                    children: data!.map((item) {
                      index++;
                      return Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: index == 1 ? 0 : 18,
                        ),
                        child: ItemView(item),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).